# Linux empty buffer cache command permission denied

Tags: command-line, memory, permissions, centos, cache

I'm using the following commands to flush cache:

```
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

When I use one of the above commands, I get the following:

```
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

My system  running CentOS 6.5, I logged in as root via SSH.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

On a shared kernel system like OpenVZ or Virtuzzo the containers do not have this level of access to the virtual memory manager.